# Regex - dont mind the order?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to crete a regex which can accept general SQL  / Js date such as:

31 feb 2012

I already made a regex :

```
(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[ ]+(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[ ]+[12]\d{3}$
```

but how can i tell the regex to *ignore* the appearence order of the items :

so it can accept  :

```
  Apr 31 2010
  2010 Apr 31 
  ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution using lookahead assertions:

```
var myregexp = /^(?=.*(\b[A-Za-z]{3}\b))(?=.*(\b\d{1,2}\b))(?=.*(\b\d{4}\b))/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    month = match[1];
    days = match[2];
    year = match[3];
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^             # Start of string
(?=           # Look ahead to see if the following can be matched:
 .*           #  Any number of characters
 (            #  followed by (capturing this in group no. 1)
  \b          #  Start of word
  [A-Za-z]{3} #  Three ASCII letters
  \b          #  End of word
 )            # End of capturing group no. 1
)             # End of lookahead assertion.
(?=           # Look ahead to see if the following can be matched:
 .*           #  Any number of characters
 (            #  followed by (capturing this in group no. 1)
  \b\d{1,2}\b #  a one- or two-digit number
 )            # etc.
)
(?=           # Lookahead no. 3
 .*
 (
  \b\d{4}\b   #  a four-digit number
 )
)
```

Comment: Is this still a regular (strictly speaking) expression, btw? :)

Comment: @tim did you write the text comments by yourself  , or by solftware ? which one ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I wrote them myself.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Absolutely, yes. This regex is good for extracting, not so good for validating. I may have misinterpreted what Royi meant by "accepting".

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Because you misplaced the parentheses around the second alternation, therefore the `\b`s weren't applied to all items in the alternation. Try this: `alert(/^(?=.*(\b(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\b))(?=.*(\b[12]\d{3}\b))(?=.*\b(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\b)/i.test('feb cc 2012'));`

Comment: im trying to constrait the expression to include $ at the end and than it stops working....( i want to match from ^ to $)

Comment: can you please answer my last comment ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The lookaheads don't actually consume any characters in the match, therefore you need to add `.*$` at the very end of the regex to make it match the whole string (although of course you already know beforehand what that string is, therefore I had omitted this from my answer).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13055/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-tim-pietzcker)

Answer (score 1):

You should pool the characters into groups, and then you can use OR to accept them in the different orders in which they occur in your strings. You cannot built a general regex that can work with any order - you have to clearly specify all the orders in which they occur.

Comment: To add in this answer: You can create variables that has regex for each component (date, month, year), then create a regex by specifying them in the acceptable orders using `|`. e.g. `"(" + DAY + " +" + MONTH + " +" + YEAR + "|" + YEAR + " +" + MONTH + " +" + DAY + ")"`